how to implement BEP322 in python or nodejs
In Bep322. there is a MEV builder api.
if i want to make my transection faster.i can direct send bnb to miner address in the same bundle.
but how i know what miner address i need to send bnb with.
how i do it in nodejs or python.
do i or i just simply build my own builder node and make a miner address and send bnb to my miner address myself and it will send to validator same time?
like sending bundle how to calculate how much gsa i shoud pay
